# MVC4 Request headers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have rather bizarre behaviour in my MVC web application.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class NoCacheFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
            ctx.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache);
}
```

I am adding this filter class to GlobalFilterCollection so that it runs on every action.

I am attempting to override this header selectively in one of my home controller action method.
       Response.Headers.Remove("Cache-Control");
       Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private,must-revalidate,proxy-revalidate ");

Problem is non these code are setting the correct values. When I inspect the values in response header the Cache-Control is set to "private, s-maxage=0".  I scanned all my code to see if I was explicitly doing so anywhere but I don't see myself doing that. The odd thing is If I call 
Response.Cache.SetNoStore(); or Any methods  of Response.Cache. the response value of Cache-Control then changes. I am not sure why Response.AddHeader or AppendHeader doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The "Cache-Control" response header in ASP.NET is special and shouldn't be set explicitly.  Instead, use the first-class APIs hanging off of the `Response.Cache` object as you've already found.

Answer (score 0):

Could you solve it by adding some conditional logic before performing `ctx.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache)`?

Basically, you could create another filter named [ApplyCache] to apply to your action method for which you don't want no-cache set, and in NoCacheFilterAttribute, you can do this,

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class NoCacheFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext ctx)
   {
      if (!ctx.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.GetFilters().Contains(new ApplyCache()) && !ctx.ActionDescriptor.GetFilters().Contains(new ApplyCache())              
         {
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
         }
   }
}
```

For MVC this could be,

```
public class ApplyCache: System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
    }

public class NoCache: System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
           if (!actionExecutedContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(ApplyCache), true))
           {
                actionExecutedContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
           }
        }
    }
```

and you want to add both filters to your global collection.

```
public static void RegisterMvcFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new ApplyCache());
    filters.Add(new NoCache());
}
```

Comment: Well. This doesn't work when I try to add to GlobalFilterCollection. Looks like the ActionFilterAttribute you proposed belongs to System.Web.Http.Filters and not System.Web.Mvc

Comment: I thought it was Web API. For MVC, you can follow a similar approach but change the condition check to !actionContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(ApplyCache), true)

Comment: The code executes fine. Still, the header value does not change when inspecting in chrome and FF inspect element window (Yes, I did cleared cached on browser side as well). I added break point to inspect if the header value changes, I do see the values changing in the Response.Headers collection. But when the page comes back the value in the Cache-Control does not change. For some reason it prefers  using the value from Response.Cache when writing the final contents

Answer (score 0):

OK.  This is what I found out. Any time anywhere in your code if you use (any other NuGet library may be setting the headers) following code:

```
 Response.Cache.SetNoStore(); //or any other .SetXXX; methods
```

, the headers are written to buffer, and if you issue say following code (some examples using this in ActionFilterAttribute):

```
 HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current; 
 ctx.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "private, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate ");
 ctx.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate ");
 ctx.Response.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
```

to modify the header, the header values are not written. Only way to reset the header is to issue following line of code and then the issue the code above or call Response.Cache.SetXXX methods.

```
 ctx.Response.ClearHeaders();
```

The [Response.Cache](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/HttpCachePolicy.cs)  does not provide a mechanism to reset the response headers values that were set using .SetXXXX methods. If Response.Cache.SetXXX method was never called then calling Response.AppendHeader, AddHeader or Headers.Set will work without any need to call Response.ClearHeaders();